# Mongoose callback function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm learning nodejs, express and mongoose. I came up with a question regarding the findOne function used to retrieve a document from the database.
Normally, you would use it like this:

```
 Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id},function(error, result){
      res.send(result);
});
```

But  when I tried to do the following, it failed (I did it just for the sake of learning):

```
 Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, returnFunction(res));

 function returnFunction(res,error, result){ 
     //error and result  are provided by the findOne callback function
     return function(){
           res.send(result); //doesnt work
      };
  }
```

But if I pass the parameters to the inner function, it works perfectly:

```
Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, returnFunction(res));

 function returnFunction(res,error, result){ 
       //error and result  are provided by the findOne callback function
       return function(res,result){
             res.send(result); 
       };
 }
```

Isn't the inner function supposed to have access to the outer functions variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you only pass `res` so `error` and `result` are undefined.

Comment: But arent error and result  implicit in the  function? Because as I said, the last code worked perfectly, even if I didnt pass those variables.

Comment: They are implicit to *the function you return*, not the one you call yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `returnFunction(res)` you are actually returning a function.

If you define your function like:

```
function returnFunction(res, error, result){ 
     return function(){
           res.send(result);
      };
  }
```

you are returning a function that takes no argument. This would be the equivalent of

```
 Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(){
      res.send(result);  // result is undefined here
});
```

But if you define your function like:

```
function returnFunction(res){ 
       return function(error, result){
             res.send(result); // res is defined
       };
```

it's OK. This would be the equivalent of:

```
Product.findOne({_id: req.params.id},function(error, result){
      res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: I get it now! Thanks very much!! :)